# How can I keep double quotation marks inside of a href without changing the code containing the double quotation marks?

Tags: javascript, html, href

```
javascript:function gcloak() { var link = document.querySelector("link[rel*='icon']") || document.createElement('link');link.type = 'image/x-icon';link.rel = 'shortcut icon';link.href = 'https://ssl.gstatic.com/docs/doclist/images/infinite_arrow_favicon_5.ico';document.title = 'My Drive - Google Drive';console.log(document.title);document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(link) };gcloak();setInterval(gcloak, 1000);
```

I am trying to add this code to a hyperlink so i will be able to drag it to my bookmarks bar. The issue is that it won't include the double quotation marks at

```
("link[rel*='icon']")
```

and just ends at

```
javascript:function gcloak() { var link = document.querySelector(
```

I have tried changing the double quotes to single quotes but that makes the javascript not work.

Comment: You should be able to just use `'link[rel*=icon]'` instead, the quotes around the attribute value in that selector are not strictly necessary to begin with.

Comment: Side note: embedding code in an HTML attribute is not the best practice. Why not put your code in a `script`?

Comment: Not sure if I understand your question but you can escape double quotes in JavaScript with `\"` so you can try `("link[rel*=\"icon\"]")`

Comment: and you can also do what @Thomas did in his answer.

Answer (score 2):

if you use backticks (`) instead of double or single quotes then you can write any of single double and even multiline inside it.

```js
`link[rel*='icon']`
```

Answer (score 1):

Encode double quotes in attributes using `&quot;`:

```html
<a href="javascript:console.log(&quot;clicked!&quot;)">Bookmark me</a>
```

Browsers don't execute `javascript:` URLs when clicked, but you can hover over the link to see the unescaped URL, and presumably it works when bookmarked.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. And Bookmarklets are javascript that you can put into the URL of a bookmark to make the javascript run when the bookmark is clicked.